# Filling a table with array with values from plist

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, plist

I'm trying to populate a table view with an array with values from a plist. Everything looks right but when I compile it doesn't show any table what so ever. Any clues as to why?

```
    #import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

-(void) setAge:(int)age{
    _age = age;
}
-(int) age {
    return _age;
}

-(void) setName:(NSString *)name{
    _name = name;
}
-(NSString *) name{
    return _name;
}
-(void) setJob:(NSString *)job{
    _job = job;
}
-(NSString *) job{
    return _job;
}



    @interface Person : NSObject {
    int _age;
    NSString * _name;
    NSString * _job;
}

-(void) setAge: (int) age;
-(int) age;

-(void) setName: (NSString *) name;
-(NSString *) name;

-(void) setJob: (NSString *) job;
-(NSString *) job;

-(NSString *) summaryString;

@end


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PeopleListViewController : UITableViewController
//Array to hold list of people
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *people;
@end




    #import "PeopleListViewController.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface PeopleListViewController ()

@end

@implementation PeopleListViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *peopleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"people" ofType:@"plist"]];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array){
        Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
        person.job = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        person.age = [[dict objectForKey:@"age"] intValue];
        person.job = [dict objectForKey:@"job"];
        [peopleArray addObject:person];

    }
    self.people = peopleArray;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 15;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =
    [[self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does a log of self.people show what you expect?

Comment: BTW, all the code in Person.m would be unnecessary (as well as the ivar declarations and method declarations in the .h file) if you create properties for age, name and job instead.

Comment: Gonna be honest, I'm really new to this - how would I do that?

Comment: How would you do what? Log the array? Create Properties?

Comment: Log the array, and the Person class is from another file, so I thought it would be easier to just add them to this one

Comment: Put NSLog(@"%@",self.people) as the last line in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @rdelmar logging `self.people` won't help much without a good `description` method in the `Person` class.

Comment: Why is your `numberOfRowsInSection` hardcode to return `15`? Change it to return `self.people.count`.

Comment: @rmaddy, it would tell me if it's empty, which might be the problem (if array is empty).

Comment: Okay, I've done that. It's still just showing a white screen though :/

Comment: @rdelmar True but it doesn't indicate whether any of the objects have a value for `name`.

Comment: You could also use the **debugger**. Set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`, single-step and inspect the variables. Then set a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`...

Comment: Made a bit of progress, I think my problem was that I wasn't configuring the Appdelegate.m corrently, but now when I run it it stops and shows me the main method highlighted in green. Literally no idea why

Comment: Well, neither do any of us, since you didn't say what you have in the app delegate.

Comment: @Greg Why? That's not needed.